# Trying to understand the set $D(f, \epsilon , P)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently I am reading this [paper](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matlhh/preprints/zeroindex.pdf). In page $2$, there is this set $D(f, \epsilon , P)$ is defined as follows: $($$P$ is a closed subset of $X$$)$

Let $\epsilon >0$ and a function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given. For any $P \in C$, let $D(f, \epsilon , P)$ be the set of all $x \in P$ such that for any neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, there exists $x_1, x_2 \in P \cap U$ such that $d_Y(f(x_1),f(x_2)) \geq \epsilon$. $($I think there is a typo in the paper, the metric should be from $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $Y$ as I don't see any $Y$ before this paragraph. $)$

I am trying to understand the set $D(f, \epsilon , P)$ by letting $X = \mathbb{R}, f(x)=x^2, P=[0,1]$. But I face difficulty in visualising it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: For continuous functions (on $P$) the set is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could we not visualise $D(f,\epsilon,P)$ as the set of all points near which $f$ exhibits discontinuities of varying degrees of severity? I.e. there are always two points arbitrarily close to $x$ which $f$ 'separates' from one another in the image space (in this case $\mathbb{R}).$

For $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = -\frac{\epsilon}{2}, x \in (-\infty,0)$ and $f(x) = \frac{\epsilon}{2}, x \in (0,\infty)$ with $f(0) = 0,$ then $0 \in D(f,\epsilon,[-1,1])$ because in any $\delta$-interval around $0$ we have $d(f(-\delta/2),f(\delta/2))=\epsilon.$

Apologies if I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Suppose $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$. Then for any $\epsilon \leq 1$, $D(f,\epsilon,P)=\mathbb{Z} \cap P$. Otherwise, $D(f,\epsilon,P)=\emptyset$, am I right?

Comment: Yes according to the definition that seems good, depending how $P$ is defined. If $P=[1,\infty)$ then $1\notin D$ for $\epsilon\leq 1$

Comment: If $P= \mathbb{R}$, then the set is $\mathbb{Z}$ for $\epsilon \leq 1$?

Comment: Yes that seems correct. For $P=[0,1],$ it would be nice to think about what $D(f,\epsilon,P)$ would look like for a function such as $$ f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}  \Big \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \Big \rfloor & x>0 \\ 0 & x = 0 \end{array} \right. $$ Even better would be $D\left( \frac{1}{f}, \epsilon, P\right).$ Or even [Thomae's Function][1].


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function